# signalR core define transport

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

Before the final release of signalR core. I was able to send the transport when defining a new HubConnection (JavaScript)

```
var cnn = new signalR.HubConnection("/myhub", 
                                         {transport : signalrR.TransportType.LongPolling});
```

this doesn't work anymore. And i was not able to find any documentation / sample yet.

A sample or a link to the documentation would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a sample adapted from [HubConnectionBuilder.test.ts](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/blob/30a59f6df79014942620a65fb7d65f32b6b1246b/clients/ts/signalr/tests/HubConnectionBuilder.test.ts#L88-L89):

```js
const builder = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/myhub", signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets)
    .build();
```

[`withUrl`](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/blob/30a59f6df79014942620a65fb7d65f32b6b1246b/clients/ts/signalr/src/HubConnectionBuilder.ts#L57-L74) also accepts [`IHttpConnectionOptions`](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/blob/10efae64e06f5c886a757280548d3dd35fb87d9a/clients/ts/signalr/src/IHttpConnectionOptions.ts) so this would work too:

```js
const builder = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/myhub", { transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets })
    .build();
```